# can sent data from database node to jade

Tags: node.js, parsing, express, orm, pug

im new on nodejs
i can't send data from select db to jade, but work in json

```
router.get('/view-profil', function(req, res, next){

    req.models.users.all({id:16}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        res.send({
            status:'error',
            data:err
        });
    } else {
        res.send({
            status:'ok',
            data:results
        });
    console.log(results)
    // results.forEach(function(data){
    //  console.log(data);
    // });

        // res.render('user/user-profil', { title: 'User Profil', userdata:results });

    }

    });

});
```

view

```
 extends ../layout

block content
  h1= title
  p View All User to #{title}
  p {userdata.nickname}
  a(href='/user') Back to user
```

when i do res.send() this work but doesn't work when i render just title show up.

```
res.render('user/user-profil', { title: 'User Profil', userdata:results });
```

Im i wrong ? 
thanks before

Comment: What is the output of console.log(results)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array to jade, so you need to choose first element of it:

```
extends ../layout

block content
  h1= title
  p View All User to #{title}
  p {userdata[0].nickname}
  a(href='/user') Back to use
```

Otherwise you need to use function req.models.users.findById if you use Mongoose for an ORM.

Comment: still doesn't work, actually i want to show all data id:16 just for try and i using postgres. can u help me with any solutions. in console any field just like this nickname: [Getter/Setter],
    email: [Getter/Setter],
    fullname: [Getter/Setter] thanks before

Comment: at firs my code loo like this --> req.models.users.find({id:16}, function(err, results) { but still doesn't work

Comment: Can you link to library you install?